# First meeting with Roger is missing in Training Day?

Tags: training-day

We've watched the [Training Day](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0139654/) the other day on Youtube TV and after [reading about it on Fandom](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Roger_(Training_Day)) I realized that first scene with Roger is missing.

We went from PCP smoking straight to alley scene, [while in the script](https://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/Training_Day.pdf) and fandom page it says that the main characters met with Roger between these scenes. In fact we missing pages 25-32 from the script.

Was there a special cut of that scene? Why didn't it make on Youtube TV?

Comment: I would not say they had cut it out, I remember they meet Roger and they talk about lot of thing, including Roger recognises Jake as a Strong Safety from Hollywood High.